# How do we read dynamically changing value from express session and display the value on angular front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, session

I have been working with JavaScript for sometime but recently had to use Angular (v7). I am stuck with a situation where I've a session value set in express session and the value is very dynamic. I am not able to display this value in my view in real-time.

This is my first question on SO, and I know I can be very vague, but please let me know if you think you can help me. I can elaborate more if needed.

I have made a Observale variable in my component, and a service is there to call the express controller, which in turn calls express model where a session value is read and returned.

Now this call is happening only for one time, but I want this call to return session value automatically, whenever it changes.

app.component.html

```js
<button *ngIf="sessionValue$ | async as sval">
     {{sval.status}}
</button>
```

app.component.ts

```js
this.sessionValue$: Observable<any>;

ngOnChanges(change) {
    this.intialise();
    this.sessionValue$ = this.sessionService.get();
  }
```

sessionService.ts

```js
url = environment.appUrl + 'session';
get(): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get<any>(this.url + '/status');
  }
```

express.session.controller.js

```js
exports.status = function (req, res) {
  try {
    sessioModel.get(req.session, function (result) {
      res.status(200).send(result);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
  }
}
```

express.session.model.js

```js
exports.get= function (session, handleResponse) {
  var sessionValue= session['variableMe'];
  const retVal= sessionValue['nowValue'];

  if (!retVal) {
    handleResponse({ status: "" });
  } else {

    handleResponse({ status: retVal });
  }
};
```

I expect the value on html page to change every time session variable changes its value.

Comment: Have a look at ```server-sent events```, I think it fits your use case. There are libraries and middlewares to implement sse for node and express. You could also use something like long polling ( a popular library that implements long polling is Comet) or short polling.There are pros and cons of each so don't be afraid to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using sockets, this would allow you to communicate in real-time between the front end and backend without having to do a service call every time. This is a pretty good [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io) with good documentation on how to get set up.

The backend is a bit trickier to get set up, so if you have trouble be sure to reach out for help.